# Shopify and MailChimp - Issue with 1 mc:repeatable with multiple mc:edit

Tags: html, html-email, shopify, mailchimp

I'm not sure what is wrong with this code of mine. So I have one big container with mc:repeatable and nested with tables, and the td with mc:edit.

This is a 2 column template.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr mc:repeatable="repeat_1">
    <td width="50%" class="leftColumnContent" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="item">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div mc:edit="image_00">
                        <img src="http://chimpified.com/images/templates/260.gif" style="max-width:260px;display:block;margin-bottom:1em;" class="ch_image" />
                    </div>
                    <div mc:edit="content_00">
                        <h4 class="h4">Product Title</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ipsum odio, tristique sed pellentesque eget, cursus quis turpis. Mauris sapien massa, vestibulum ut interdum quis, pulvinar sit amet orci.</p>
                        <p class="ch_meta"><strong class="price ch_price">$0.00</strong> <span class="ch_pipe">|</span> <a href="#" target="_blank" class="ch_link">View product</a></p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="50%" class="rightColumnContent" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="item">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div mc:edit="image_01">
                        <img src="http://chimpified.com/images/templates/260.gif" style="max-width:260px;display:block;margin-bottom:1em;" class="ch_image" />
                    </div>
                    <div mc:edit="content_01">
                        <h4 class="h4">Product Title</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ipsum odio, tristique sed pellentesque eget, cursus quis turpis. Mauris sapien massa, vestibulum ut interdum quis, pulvinar sit amet orci.</p>
                        <p class="ch_meta"><strong class="price ch_price">$0.00</strong> <span class="ch_pipe">|</span> <a href="#" target="_blank" class="ch_link">View product</a></p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm using chimpified plugin with shopify. I selected 4 products to be display in the email. But when I look at the design preview, I only seeing the 1st column filled with product info. Nothing on the 2nd column. Table is repeated.

I'm not sure why the 2nd column doesn't have any info being fill in.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there is no ending table tag. Also, your "repeat_1" is on a table row, and not a table itself. You can refer to the templates that are at http://chimpified.com/templates to see how to repeat sections. It appears that a table needs to be repeated, and not a table row. In the example, there is a table with two columns, and each column contains a repeatable table.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I noticed I left out the closing table tag but that doesn't matter.

I actually got the code from chimpified template. So you are saying repeatable section is only allow on table?

I have tried that too. The result is still the same.